# Delete multiple files on PowerShell command line

Tags: powershell, file-management

With PowerShell, what is the most concise way to delete multiple explicitly named files?

E.g. on *ix it would be:

```
rm subDir/a.png anotherDir/b.jpg thirdDir/c.gif
```

I'm currently using:

```
echo subDir/a.png anotherDir/b.jpg thirdDir/c.gif|rm
```

But I consider it suboptimal, so I would like to see alternatives.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can give PowerShell's `rm` cmdlet (which is itself an alias for `Remove-Item`) several files, but you need to separate them with commas.

```
rm .\subDir\a.png, .\anotherDir\b.jpg, .\thirdDir\c.gif
```

Check out `Get-Help Remove-Item` for more details. Or read [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I ended up using:

```
echo subDir/a.png anotherDir/b.jpg thirdDir/c.gif|rm
```

This uses echo to pass three string arguments to rm ([Remove-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315401.aspx)).  I believe this implicitly uses Remove-Item's `-Path` parameter.  The documentation notes that "The parameter name ("-Path") is optional" and it accepts pipeline input by value.

Comment: This is helpful for doing a copy/paste of multiple files from Git.

Answer (score 1):

Old dog's trick, define an array first.
Put your stuff in it, and RM the heck out of it.

```
$myArray = @("subDir/a.png","subDir/b.png","thirdDir/c.gif")
rm $myArray
```

Answer (score 0):

trick to remove similar extension files using * wildcard.

remove all .png files.

```
rm ./*.png
```

remove all .extension files e.g `.eslintrc, .gitignore, .stylelintrc.json` etc

```
rm ./.*
```

Comment: nice and easy..

Comment: Your answer is correct but needs a caveat IMO. Rm is one of the unforgiving commands you should treat like a weapon and globs/wildcards make it like aiming at a crowd. Do a dry-run, use rm's interactive option, use the tab key and check the expansions, or put together a dummy environment to safely run the command and check the results. You could even rely on backups so you can `rm` freely without risking data. As an example, this solution (correctly) removes `.file.txt.swp` generated by Vim to maintain changes to `file.txt`, but in Windows both files would be hidden and easily overlooked.